# how do i sign my JWT with rsa key in swift?

Tags: java, swift, jwt, rsa

i'm trying to create a JWT and for that i need a RSA key. I already have a working Java code, but i have to get it working in SWIFT. i have a private key, that is used in the java version to create the RSA key the following way:

```
private static RSAPrivateKey getPrivateKey(String key) {

    PrivateKey privateKey = null;
    final String algorithm = "RSA";
    try {
        byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(key.getBytes());
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
    } catch (Exception e) {
                                           
    }
}
```

this key is then used to create the Algorithm `Algorithm alg = Algorithm.RSA256(null, privateKey)` which is then used to sign the JWT token.

The classes used here are from java.security, com.auth0 and org.apache.commons.codec

What i tried in swift is putting the key(the one that is given to the above function) into a file

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
[the actual key]
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and then call

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "privateKey", ofType: "key")
let privateKeyPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
let privateKey: Data = try Data(contentsOf: privateKeyPath, options: .alwaysMapped)
let jwtSigner = JWTSigner.rs256(privateKey: privateKey)
let signedJwt = try jwt.sign(using: jwtSigner)
```

but this gives me the error

`"Provided private key could not be used to sign JWT", internalError: SwiftJWT.JWTError.(unknown context at $1047b9eec).InternalError.invalidPrivateKey)`

the library i'm using here is https://github.com/Kitura/Swift-JWT.git

can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Edit: I just looked into the API myself, and it seems the function `JWTSigner.rs256(privateKey:` actually expects a PEM encoded data containing the RSA key. Well, in this case there seems to be a more subtle error with the RSA key.

Comment: so, what does that mean?

Comment: I guess, the error is thrown from the ASN.1 parser which expects a different format of the content in the PEM. A PEM container can contain a variety of things, a certificate, a private key, etc.. As a file, it may have various file extensions: .pem, .key, .cer, .cert, etc.. The RSA private key's attributes may not be understood by the ASN.1 parser. A PEM is defined in [RFC 7468](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7468). You may use another tool to check if the ASN.1 file is wellformed. Once you get the decoded body of the PEM, you may use this tool: https://asn1.io/asn1playground/